# Excel VBA how to prevent messed up when inserted new rows?

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have this line in a macro:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A5").Value
```

How can I programatically (only via VBA) make it so that if rows or columns are inserted in sheet 1 between `A1` and `A2`, `A1`, `B2`, it will not mess up since the rows numbers are changed?

Comment: Are you saying you want `Sheets("sheet2").Range("A5").Value` to adjust down if more rows are inserted above it? If no, please clarify which sheet the insertion happens on and which cells would be messed up.

Comment: You can use named ranges if you don't need to track too many cells.

Comment: @DougGlancy i mean sheet in sheet 1 when insertion appears from the source

Comment: I was going to make the same general comment as @TimWilliams - you could probably use named ranges - but wanted to get a better feel for what you're dealing with. What I hear you saying is that inserting rows between A1 and A2 will affect the location of A1, which isn't the case. Perhaps you mean inserted above A1? Feel free to use more words to describe your situation. Or just go with the suggestion and use named ranges.

Comment: Named ranges might work for this case but i've alot of cells to assign values from sheet2.  i cant be giving each cell columns a ranged name ? that will be like 200 columns.. or perhaps i need to.. just another questions say i assign the how column A1 as named range "A1Range" how do traverse to the nth row in the range so i can set value to?

Comment: if named ranges are not the answer then you need to expand the question with some screen prints so we can see the exact context of `A1` and `A5` ....need to know what is around them; are they at the bottom of tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of avoiding these sort of problems is to use `Named ranges`.

If `A1` is and important place for a result it could be called "myResult" and if `A5` is an important place for input then it could be called "myInput". Your code would then change to:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Range("myResult").Value = Sheets("sheet2").Range("myInput").Value
```

Doesn't matter how many columns or rows you now insert the above code will always find the same cells.

Or am I misinterpreting the question?

If these ranges `A1` and `A5` are actually always in the same relative position in a table e.g. bottom right hand corner, then the solution would be different.

Comment: thanks whytheq, ur intepretation is correct. But how do i access the 3rd row of the named ranges? say i've the entire A set as named range.. i want to set the 3rd row only?

Comment: I've just named a single cell "myResult"....if you name the whole column "myResult" then I think you'll be running into some problems. Can you add screen prints to the OP to help us interpret the question a little. Lots of people with lots of experience on here so I suspect the answer to your question is easy enough but some more detail is required